# Selling domain names for a reasonable price

Tags: domains, reseller

So I have this domain name "theverbproject.com" that I bought back in December. I recently got an offer for 150.00. I'm debating whether I should sell it or hold out for however longer it takes for another offer.

Is 150 a reasonable offer, or should I hold onto it?

Comment: How much traffic does it get.  If the answer is 'virtually none' then snap sell it.

Comment: It was forwarded so no real record of anything. Is a domain parking service like Sedo worth it, in comparison?